# Unable to start Virtual machine after installation

Tags: virtual-machine, intel, vt-x

Unable to start Virtual machine after installation of vm and ubuntu iso file with - Error while powering on: This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.

Intel VT-x might be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since changing this setting.

(1) Verify that the BIOS/firmware settings enable Intel VT-x and disable 'trusted execution.'

(2) Power-cycle the host if either of these BIOS/firmware settings have been changed.

(3) Power-cycle the host if you have not done so since installing VMware Player.

(4) Update the host's BIOS/firmware to the latest version.

This host does not support "Intel EPT" hardware assisted MMU virtualization.

VMware Player does not support the user level monitor on this host.

Module 'MonitorMode' power on failed.

Failed to start the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

1- You have to restart your pc to access the BIOS setting, when its starting up you should press del or f2.

2- Then you have to find INTEL VMX option (you can search with f9)

3- You should just enable that option

*(Advanced Mode>Advance>CPU Configuration>Intel (VMX) Virtualization Technology (Disable > Enable ))

4- press f10 to save

5- Now you can use your virtual machine easily

*But the different mainboard's brands may have different BIOS menus so I will put the binds which you can use on different brands below  to open the BIOS menu.

---

ASRock: F2 or DEL

ASUS: F2 for all PCs, F2 or DEL for Motherboards

Acer: F2 or DEL

Dell: F2 or F12

ECS: DEL

Gigabyte / Aorus: F2 or DEL

HP: F10

Lenovo (Consumer Laptops): F2 or Fn + F2

Lenovo (Desktops): F1

Lenovo (ThinkPads): Enter then F1.

MSI: DEL for motherboards and PCs

Microsoft Surface Tablets: Press and hold volume up button.

Origin PC: F2

Samsung: F2

Toshiba: F2

Zotac: DEL

---

I hope That was helpful.